# intersection function gets stuck after output

Tags: c++, function, data-structures, linked-list, intersection

```
void intersectionLists(LinkedList argList) {
    bool common = false;
    ListNode* thisCurrentPointer{headPointer};
    ListNode* argCurrentPointer;
    cout <<"common elements between both lists are:\n";

    while(thisCurrentPointer != nullptr) {

        argCurrentPointer = argList.getHeadReference();
        while(argCurrentPointer != nullptr){

            if(thisCurrentPointer->data == argCurrentPointer->data) {
                cout <<thisCurrentPointer->data;
                common = true;
                break;
            }
            argCurrentPointer = argCurrentPointer->nextPointer;
        }
        thisCurrentPointer = thisCurrentPointer->nextPointer;
    }
    if(!common) {
        cout <<"none\n";
    }
    thisCurrentPointer = nullptr;
    argCurrentPointer = nullptr;
    delete thisCurrentPointer;
    delete argCurrentPointer;
}
```

Hello everyone,

Iwas making this function for intersection in the linkedList class, which has the parameter of another linkedList object, one utility function i am using on line 9 is getHeadReference(), which simply returns the address stored in the headPointer (i am using this function in order to get argCurrentPointer to point at the head of the list that came in the parameter).

Anyway.. the function gives perfectly fine output of whatever two linked lists are but the control get "stuck" right after its execution, the control freezes, and a huge garbage value is returned, i really hope i am being clear.

I have dry run the code i can not seem to find the problem. Even in main when i call another function after the execution of "intersectionLists" function, the called function gets executed properly without any delay but the control can't seem to exit main after all the work is done, when i don't call this intersection code, no hang or delay whatsoever is observed, please help. Thank you.

Comment: Could please you split the paragraph? it is quite hard to read

Comment: sure, here you go.

Comment: the `delete` lines at the end is unnecessary.

Comment: can you also add the constructor and destructor of the `LinkedList` class? there's a big chance the "stuck" is from there since you're passing a `LinkedList` object by value. after the function, that parameter will get destructed.

Comment: ok, i erased the delete statements, still facing the same problem :(

Comment: omg i just passed the linked list in argument of the function by reference and it worked.. but how? there was no hang and the program executed like a breeze,

Comment: can you please explain what would be the difference between void intersectionLists(LinkedList argList) and void intersectionLists(LinkedList& argList)..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you detele `thisCurrentPointer` and `argCurrentPointer` after setting them to null. It is not necessary to do any deletion after as you are not duplicating your nodes.

Comment: if i delete them without making them null, they would delete with themselves the node at which they are pointing. by the way i still tried what you said, still facing the same problem.

Comment: apparently the problem was that i was not passing the LinkedList object by reference..